# How to access project.test (Laragon virtual host) from other device in one network WIFI?

Tags: localhost, wifi, virtualhost, laragon, pretty-urls

I managed to access my local project on a server pc using a smartphone on one network by typing ipAddressServer/projectName/public. but I can't access it with virtual host projectName.test. how to access with virtual host?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.